# DDoS attack simulation using MININET

Tags: ddos, security

I´m developing some dynamic security policies using SDN, one of them consist in how the network should respond to a DDoS attack detection. So, I would like to test my policies but I'm having some problems trying to recreate an attack in a mininet topology.

Is there any documentation about how to simulate a DDoS attack with mininet?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which OF controller you are using, but here is a very good research project on this very topic for Floodlight SDN controller. I intend to use this in my own mininet when finished with my current project. [Floodlight OpenFlow DDoS](http://www.slideshare.net/YoavFrancis/floodlight-openflow-ddos)